# why does my button not appear on my JPanel - Java

Tags: java, swing

Or maybe my JPanel is not appearing at all.

I am trying to have a JPanel at the bottom of the screen that hold several buttons. Can someone set me strait?

```
public class MyAWTMenu extends java.awt.Frame// implements ActionListener 
{
public void init() { 
setBackground( Color.white );
JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("test");
 b1.setVisible(true);
    bottom.add(b1);
    bottom.setVisible(true);
    add(bottom,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
public static void main( String args [] ) {

    MyAWTMenu objAppFrame = new MyAWTMenu();

    objAppFrame.addWindowListener(      //Register an anonymous class as a listener.
         new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ) 
            {  
               System.exit( 0 );
            }
         }
    );
    objAppFrame.init();
    objAppFrame.setSize( 760, 378);
    objAppFrame.setVisible( true );                    

  }
```

Comment: nothing shows up, not an empty black panel, nothing. If i don't use a panel and just add the button directly it fills up the whole screen

Comment: aren't you adding panel to itself? or it may be too late for today :) yes, it's too late (formatting has confused me)

Comment: I don't think so because the class extends Frame, so add(panel) would be this.add(panel) which would be adding it to the frame. I think -- edit: haha sorry about the formatting, it's hard to format with this thing

Comment: I haven't used Java for GUI work in a long time, but could this be because you're mixing AWT and Swing components? Try using `Panel` instead of `JPanel` and `Button` instead of `JButton` maybe?

Comment: That code works for me. I put it in Eclipse and it worked fine.

Comment: Works for me too, I was just wondering if the screwiness is because he's mixing APIs.

Comment: @skaffman, thanks for the formatting; @everyoneElse, When I went to JFrame rather then Frame it fixed everything so I think you guys were right. The way barti did it below is way better than my way and it works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd better rewrite it as follows:

```
public class FooFrame extends JFrame {

    public FooFrame() {

        // your code, copy/pasted
        setBackground(Color.white);
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("test");
        bottom.add(b1);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // set size & pack
        Dimension size = new Dimension(400, 400);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FooFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: using jframe rather than frame solved my problems, however, using your solution the frame shows up really really small in the top left hand corner of the screen.

Comment: I've added min size & location setting, btw.

Answer (score 1):

`add(bottom,BorderLayout.SOUTH);`
 in your `init()`

Here's your code that i was running. It seems to work fine for me. I did add a call to `pack();`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyAWTMenu extends java.awt.Frame// implements ActionListener
{

    public void init() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("test");
        bottom.add(b1);
        bottom.setVisible(true);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MyAWTMenu objAppFrame = new MyAWTMenu();

        objAppFrame.addWindowListener( //Register an anonymous class as a listener.
                new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        objAppFrame.init();
        objAppFrame.setSize(760, 378);
        objAppFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, actually read your question wrong, try the changes above. This will add a black panel with a button to the bottom of your frame.

Comment: ok. so actually both of your answer were right. I needed to BOTH say b1.setVisible(true) and use .SOTUH. now I want to know why, why does saying .CENTER not work? so odd...

Comment: Changing it from CENTER to SOUTH most definitely does something. It will move your black JPanel to the southern part of the Frame while leaving the upper portion white.

Comment: do i need some sorta refresh? it seems as though nothing shows up untill after a put my curser over where it should be.

Comment: Something is going wrong. No matter what, the background of the pannel is not black. And the button only shows up when i drag my cursor over it... like it needs to refresh. if i use .CENTER nothing shows up at all

Comment: You should call repaint() after you make your changes to the GUI. And... the components are laid out according to their preferred sizes and the constraints of the container's size. The NORTH and SOUTH components may be stretched horizontally; the EAST and WEST components may be stretched vertically; the CENTER component may stretch both horizontally and vertically to fill any space left over. When you added them to the CENTER, it stretched your panel to fill the space.

Comment: barti_ddu code above is def a better way to do it. Swing and AWT takes a little time to learn the litte nuances of it.

Comment: still didn't do anything. i went calling repaint everywhere. i changed the Frame to JFrame per bart's solution and everything just started working...

Comment: I posted the code I was running for you example. See if it does what your expecting.

Comment: lol yes i know! i learned it a couple years ago, now i'm trying to re-learn it. I don't remember much. I now do mostly html, javascript, JQuery, database work which I like much better :)

Comment: im not sure what your asking?

Comment: Works perfect! Same effect as barti's